# this.state.articles.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why is this not working? I get data from `parseData` but it says `map isn't a function`. Why?

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.articles.map is not a function

````
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: {},
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let url =
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=<API_KEY>";
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
    console.log(parseData);
    this.setState({ articles: parseData.articles });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container my-3">
        <h2>NewsHunters -Headlines</h2>
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.articles.map((e) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4" key={e.url}>
                <NewsItem
                  title={e.title ? e.title.slice(0, 45) : ""}
                  description={e.description ? e.description.slice(0, 88) : ""}
                  imageUrl={e.urlToImage}
                  newsUrl={e.url}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Because your articles is `Object`, not `Array`. Use `[]` as initial state for articles, to be able to use `Array` methods.

P.S. This is where Typescript could be helpful, I would recommend to consider using it in the future.

Comment: its working now. thanks

Comment: @NileshHazra please make sure you mark Idruskis' answer as correct if it helped you.